# Delphi x DLL x Resources

Tags: delphi

Estou criando uma DLL em DELPHI, dentro dela existe algumas funções que meu sistema vai usar. Gostaria de saber o seguinte, existe uma forma de embutir essa DLL criada em DELPHI direto no EXE através de RESOURCES ? Tendo em vista que preciso criar uma PROCEDURE no FORM, como fazer para extrair essa DLL antes do form "subir" ?

Estou usando o seguinte para subir a DLL:

```
procedure DllMessage; external 'teste.dll'
```

Gostaria de embutir essa DLL direto no executável.

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound, na verdade é o seguinte. Algumas funções vão rodar em DLL, para não ter que entregar o projeto para o cliente com várias DLL, gostaria de colocar no EXE (usando resource) e quando o form for criado (CREATE FORM) ele descompacta essas DLL, entende ? é possível será ? as DLL são criadas no próprio delphi mesmo.

Comment: Até é possível, mas porque não utilizar o bom e velho instalador? Ou compactar em um arquivo zip?

Comment: EProgrammerNotFound, porque quero entregar somente o executável para o cliente abrir e pronto. Enfim, por vários outros motivos aqui da empresa, como seria possível fazer isso ? poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound, isso que eu queria fazer mesmo, porque se eu usar o static linking, não vai subir nunca mesmo rsrss, eu queria usar algo como LOADLIBRAY mesmo, poderia me dar essa força ?

Comment: Obrigado amigo @EProgrammerNotFound, eu tentei fazer usando FREELIBRAY, mas, não sei como eu chamo a função dentro da DLL usando ele rsrsrs.

Comment: Qual a versão do Delphi que você está utilizando? Em novas versões você pode utilizar a keyword delayed e talvez possa manter o código da forma atual. Desculpe-me por não responder mais cedo, estive ocupado no trabalho, estou no horário do almoço e escrevendo uma solução pra você

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound, eu uso o DELPHI XE7.

Comment: Qual a diferença entre usar o instalador que irá extrair a DLL e você fazer isso ? O arquivo de qualquer forma não vai ficar na pasta ? Isso de qualquer forma não iria contra "os motivos da empresa"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas etapas são necessárias para efetuar o procedimento desejado. Em primeiro lugar, vamos embutir a dll dentro de um arquivo `.res`:

Primeiramente crie sua dll e exporte-a para algum lugar de fácil acesso, para que você possa utilizar o caminho mais facilmente para gerar o arquivo `.res`.

1. Criando um arquivo com a extensão `.rc`:

   1.1 Abra o notepad ou qualquer editor de textos e mande salvar com a
   extensão `.rc`, por exemplo: DLL_Resoures.rc
2. Inserindo as informações necessárias:

   2.1 No seu arquivo RC adicione as seguintes informações: 
    IdentificadorDLL **RCDATA** "NomeArquivoDll.dll"

   - O Identificador deve ser um nome que não se repita para cada dll,
   - RCDATA especifica que serão dados crus.
   - O nome do arquivo da dll, deve conter um caminho válido para que o compilador encontre essa dll no seu Disco.
3. Compilando o arquivo `.rc`:

   Para compilar o arquivo `.rc`, procure pelo executável `BRCC32.exe` dentro da pasta bin do delphi, ou abra-o pelo prompt de comandos. Pelo prompt, utilize o comando:

   `BRCC32.exe DLL_Resoures.rc`

O Compilador de resources irá gerar um arquivo `.res` com o mesmo nome do arquivo `.rc` por padrão, esse nome será utilizado para inserir dentro do seu executável

4. Configurando o executável:

   4.1 Você deve definir um local para esse arquivo RES para evitar ter que controlar manualmente toda vez que fizer alterações na DLL, para facilitar o exemplo, apenas copie o .RES para dentro da pasta da aplicação EXE e adicione a seguinte linha no início do projeto EXE:

   ```
   program SeuPrograma;       
   uses 
   X, Y, Z;    
   {$R *.res}
   (* Adicione seu RES aqui *)
   {$R DLL_RESOURCES.res} 
   .....
   ```

A diretiva {$R} permite você especificar um caminho absoluto e relativo para o arquivo, portanto, se você definir outro lugar para o res, apenas configure um caminho diferente, por exemplo:

```
    (* Irá buscar o res um diretório acima *)
    {$R ..\DLL_RESOURCES.res}
```

5. Extraindo o RES e salvando a DLL:

   5.1 Crie a seguinte função:

   ```
   procedure ExtrairDLL(const NomeResource, NomeArquivo: String);
   var
     RStream: TResourceStream;
   begin
     RStream:= TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, NomeResource, RT_RCDATA);
     try
       RStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
       RStream.SaveToFile(NomeArquivo);
     finally
       RStream.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```

   5.2 Na criação do seu formulário chame-a passando os seguintes argumentos:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     ExtrairDLL(  (* Nome da Resource: Mesmo nome que você colocou no arquivo DLL_RESOURCES.RC *)
                  'IdentificadorDLL',
                  (* - IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter: Incluiu uma / (barra) no   final do caminho
                     - ExtractFilePath: Retorna apenas o caminho do nome de   um arquivo
                     - ParamStr(0): Recupera o nome do executável: É o primeiro parâmetro do executável *)
                    IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))) + 'NomeArquivoDLL.dll'
               );
   end;
   ```

Como você está na versão XE7 você pode apenas adicionar `delayed` no final dos seus métodos `external`. Como você sempre extrairá os arquivos antes de usar, não terá problema para rodar a aplicação

```
procedure DllMessage; external 'teste.dll' delayed;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @EProgrammerNotFound, deu tudo certo.